# Display Shortcode on wordpress page

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I want to display Shortcode on my WordPress documentation page.

```
[example parameter="something"]
```

But it was executing the shortcode on my page. Instead of executing it just want to display the shortcode on my page.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `<?php echo '[example parameter="something"]'; ?>`try this..

Comment: Don’t know if wordpress provides an official way of “escaping” those ... but something like `[<span></span>example parameter="something"]` should do the trick ...

Comment: check this answer, this will help you. https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/16991/how-to-show-the-syntaxis-of-a-shortcode. So in short you just have to encapsulate your shortcode inside `[]`, for example `[[example parameter="something"]]`

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
echo do_shortcode( '[example parameter="something"]' );
```

Hope it will work Properlly